# Error about opening links in "x-www-browser" when accessing links

Tags: whonix

I got this message in my whonix VM while trying to access a link

`The following link will be opened in x-www-browser (/usr/bin/whichbrowser). Be careful if x-www-browser (usr/bin/whichbrowser) is already running as your activities might get linked`.

I'm a complete noob and still learning, so if anyone could explain this to me in easy to understand/nontechnical terms that would be great. Also, is this a concern in regards to privacy/security especially as it pertains to my Host OS (Windows 10). Also, I want to put out there that I received this message sometime after changing my default browser on my host OS (don't know if that's related in any way). Thanks again. I appreciate all and any of your help.

Comment: The message is incomplete. It's not an error message. It's a question. It has nothing to do with host settings.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by adrelanos in the comments, this has nothing to do with the settings of your Host OS.

Whonix seems to be currently set to start a some kind of "Which web browser do you want to use?" dialog whenever you click a link that would start a new web browser.

In addition, since it is a privacy-oriented distribution, it is warning you that if you use the same browser session to visit multiple sites, those visits can be linked to each other if e.g. both sites include cookies from the same advertising company.

When you already have a web browser running and attempt to start the same browser again, it normally won't start a completely new independent instance of the web browser, but instead will tell the existing browser process to open a new window. This is for the sake of both efficiency and user convenience: both windows will share the cookies, active login sessions to websites, etc.

It is likely that Whonix performs some extra actions whenever a web browser process exits, to reset the browser to a "clean" state. So, in order to achieve maximum anonymity, you might have to fully exit your web browser between visiting one website and the next.

---

`/usr/bin/x-www-browser` is a command wrapper that will be forwarding the request to your actual favorite web browser... *once you have selected one.*

Currently, it is redirecting to `/usr/bin/whichbrowser`, but this will probably change once you select a default web browser from the menu it will display, and confirm that you want Whonix to remember that as your default setting. (I have never actually used Whonix and haven't seen its browser selection menu; this is just an educated guess.)